# How to check in 2d array if length of row and column are equal?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would to like check is length of columns in array 1 is equal length of rows in array 2. But it seems my code doesn't work.

```
if(m1[0].length = m2.length) {

    document.getElementById("compute").innerHTML = "<p>True</p>";

} else {

    document.getElementById("compute").innerHTML = "<p>False</p>";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is good, but your code is wrong.

> `if(m1[0].length = m2.length)`

In this line, you took `m1[0]` array and changed its length to the length of m2 array.

Example code:

```
let myArr = ["apple", "orange", "banana"];
myArr.length = 5;
// myArr is now ["apple", "orange", "banana", undefined, undefined]
```

What you want to do is compare those two values with `==` or `===` operator.

Comment: I have made this mistake quite often